# How do I make value static in last row value?

Tags: vba, excel

Here is the code below:

```
Public n as Long ' <--above sub procedure

 With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A6").Offset(n, 0)
    If n = 0 Then
        .Value =  1
    Else
        .Value =  .Parent.Range(.Address).Offset(-1, 0) + 1
    End If
    n = n + 1
End With
```

(See pic below) If I delete 4  then click command button again it just reset back to 1. I want to make it static so even I deleted the last value of row it still continue increment from the last value.

```
Store number
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: what is your question exactly?

Comment: @GoosvandenBekerom
How do I make value still counting if I deleted the last row value then hit button again? My code above shows every time I hit button it keeps counting but when I delete the last row value it resets back to 1

Comment: I'm sorry but I really don't get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim trow As Long
    With Sheets("Sheet1") '~~> change to suit
        trow = .Range("A:A").Find(vbNullString, [A5]).Row
        With .Range("A" & trow)
            If trow = 6 Then .Value = 1 _
            Else .Value = .Offset(-1, 0).Value + 1
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Above code finds the first blank cells. If it is *A6* it assigns a value of 1.
Otherwise it assigns previous cell value plus 1. Is this what you're trying?

**Edit1:** Explanation

```
trow = .Range("A:A").Find(vbNullString, [A5]).Row
```

This finds the first empty row in *Column A* starting A5.
`[A5]` is used to return `Range("A5")` object. So it can also be written as:

```
trow = .Range("A:A").Find(vbNullString, .Range("A5")).Row
```

We used a VBA `vbNullString` constant as *What* argument in *Range Object Find Method*.
*Find Method* returns a *Range Object* so above can be written also like this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim r As Range
    With Sheets("Sheet1") '~~> change to suit
        Set r = .Range("A:A").Find(vbNullString, [A5])
        With r
            If .Row = 6 Then .Value = 1 _
            Else .Value = .Offset(-1, 0).Value + 1
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: OMG! This is what I was trying for 3nights.. Thanks I got answer now but don't know some of the line code means if so can you add some comment in every line?

Answer (score 0):

What your asking for, a button with memory doesn't sound neatly solvable using just VBA.
You could potentially have a list on a hidden sheet that gets a value added to it each time the commandButton is pressed and it writes the max of the list values back to the target cell?

Alternatively you could investigate using a scrollbar from the form control section of the developer tab with a link to your target cell. I often use this technique for interactive sheets.

**Named Range Method**

```
Public sub btnPress
    dim val as long

    val = Range("PreviousCellValue")
    set Range("PreviousCellValue") = val+1

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A6").Offset(n, 0).value = Range("PreviousCellValue")
End sub btnPress
```

Comment: Yes I've understood the request but do you comprehend the problem? How would VBA know what the value was before you deleted it without storing the result in a sheet or global variable? If its in a global variable, what happens when someone saves the sheet and reopens it? 
Would it be easier to just prevent people from deleting the cells value?

If you want to store the variable you could use a named range?